# Check that $C$ is generated by $\sigma = (1 2 3 4)$ in symmetric group $S_4$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Let the group is symmetric group $S_4$, that express the elements of $S_4$ in cycle notation, suppose the abelian subgroup $C$ of $S_4$ to be the cyclic subgroup
$$C =\{e,(1 2 3 4),(1 3)(2 4),(1 4 3 2)\}$$
How can I checked that $C$ is generated by $\sigma = (1 2 3 4)$?

What is the inverse of $a$, if $a = (1 4 3 2)$?

I know that the cyclic group is the group that generated by one element, 
I try by  $\sigma $, $\sigma^2 $,$\sigma ^3 $ and $\sigma^4 $ mod 4 but I didnot get the original  $C$, What may I do wrong to get the original $C$?

Comment: @Shaun I edit my question.

Comment: I have edited my answer, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose $\sigma$ by its successive powers, like so: $\sigma$, $\sigma^2=\sigma\circ\sigma$, $\sigma^3=\sigma^2\circ\sigma$, $\sigma^4=\sigma^3\circ\sigma$, *etc.*; you'll find that you get all elements of $C$, at which point, you can conclude that $\sigma$ generates $C$.${}^\dagger$

In the process, you will find that some power $\tau$ of $\sigma$ is an inverse of $\sigma$. Simply take $\tau$ as *the* inverse, by uniqueness, which you will see is the element given.

---

$\dagger$: In response to your edit, it appears that you have made an error in your calculations. The method we have both described is correct.

Comment: Can you write down how to get $\sigma^2$ in correct way?

Comment: Sure, @AliA.Jalil: $\sigma=(1234)$, $\sigma^2=(13)(24)$, $\sigma^3=(1432)$, and $\sigma^4=\sigma^{-1}\circ\sigma=e$.

Comment: Many thanks, but how you get this value $\sigma^2 =(13)(24)$ ?, cause when I try to get $sigma^2$ I get  $(123)(2)(321)$ please if you can explain how to get value of it or guide me to a reference that explain that

Comment: You're welcome, @AliA.Jalil. Consider the following: $$\begin{align}1\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}2\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}3\\ 3\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}4\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}1\\ 2\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}3\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}4\\ 4\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}1\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}2.\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok many thanks, if there is any reference in that for further reading will be appreciated

Comment: Again, you're welcome, @AliA.Jalil. Try Chapter 5 of Gallian's, *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"*.

Comment: again many thanks, can you explain how to find inverse of element in such group, as I asked in my question?

Comment: That's a whole other question, @AliA.Jalil, and one that has been asked on this site many times before; have a look for yourself for a while. If you are still unsure, then ask a separate question (*i.e.*, open a new thread). The answer we're commenting on, though, explains one way to find the inverse. In general, the inverse of a permutation has the same cyclic structure as the original element, only its numbers (*e.g.*, $1$ in $(12)$) are reversed.